# Correct way to customize a Bootstrap 4 tooltip width, color & arrow?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, tooltip, customization

I have some problems in Bootstrap customizing the tooltips. I want to make the tooltips wider and let it have a custom background color as well as a text color.

I've tried a bunch of different methods, however it didn't work out how I wanted it to work. Does anyone have experience with tooltip customization inside Bootstrap4?  I did already find some topics, but all of them were about Bootstrap 2 or 3.

I have designed a tooltip that I want in Photoshop, here is the image: [How I want the tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YXhR.png). This is how it looks right now: [How the tooltip is right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW8Tr.png)

This is the code that I used so far (I'm not posting the SCSS because all of it didn't work):

```
<h1 data-toggle="tooltip" title=" example">MENU LUX</h1>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Css:

```
.tooltip {
border-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
background-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
color: black;
}
```

Comment: You can change the background and text colour of the tooltip in CSS.

Comment: Yes i know , but I don't know how i can do it properly, i've already tried it multiple times in css. but none of them works fine.. Thanks

Comment: In which case please add the CSS you tried to the question. SO is here to help you debug issues, not to write code for you

Comment: I uploaded the Css thanks in advance !

Comment: When I add a class="tooltip" , it doesn't have an effect on the css, so I don't understand why this doesn't work, while it does work with other classes within bootstrap4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your CSS is that it's not specific enough to override the default styling.

To do this you can use a selector of a higher specificity than the default Bootstrap styling; note the addition of `body` to the selectors below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```css
body .tooltip-inner {
  background: rgb(151, 151, 151);
  color: black;
}
body .tooltip .arrow::before {
  border-bottom-color: rgb(151, 151, 151);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-6khuMg9gaYr5AxOqhkVIODVIvm9ynTT5J4V1cfthmT+emCG6yVmEZsRHdxlotUnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="container">
  <h1 data-toggle="tooltip" title="example">MENU LUX</h1>
</div>
```